# Show all and only rows in table 1 not in table 2 (using multiple columns)

Tags: sql-server

I have one table (Table1) that has several columns used in combination:  Name, TestName, DevName, Dept.  When each of these 4 columns have values, the record is inserted into Table2.  I need to confirm that all of the records with existing values in each of these fields within Table1 were correctly copied into Table 2.

I have created a query for it:

```
SELECT DISTINCT wr.Name,wr.TestName, wr.DEVName ,wr.Dept
FROM table2 wr
where NOT EXISTS (
SELECT NULL
FROM TABLE1 ym
WHERE ym.Name = wr.Name 
          AND ym.TestName = wr. TestName
          AND ym.DEVName = wr.DEVName 
          AND ym. Dept = wr. Dept 
          )
```

My counts are not adding up, so I believe that this is incorrect.  Can you advise me on the best way to write this query for my needs?

Comment: Would replacing 'SELECT NULL' with 'SELECT 1' work?

Comment: "All rows in Table2 that are not in Table1" is not what your query is doing.  Your query is getting all rows in Table1 that is not in Table2.

Comment: Sorry Eric, I miswrote the question.  I am running it correctly, so corrected the question

Comment: Renat -  I'm not familiar enough so have to test it.  I will let you know, am doing it now.  Thank you!

Comment: I get the same count with NULL as with 1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `EXCEPT` set operator for this one if the table definitions are identical.

```
SELECT DISTINCT ym.Name, ym.TestName, ym.DEVName, ym.Dept
FROM table1 ym
EXCEPT
SELECT DISTINCT wr.Name, wr.TestName, wr.DEVName, wr.Dept
FROM table2 wr
```

This returns distinct rows from the first table where there is not a match in the second table. Read more about `EXCEPT` and `INTERSECT` here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/set-operators-except-and-intersect-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

Answer (score 2):

Your query should do the job.  It checks anything that are in `Table1`, but not `Table2`

```
SELECT ym.Name, ym.TestName, ym.DEVName, ym.Dept
FROM Table1 ym
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM table2
    WHERE ym.Name = Name AND ym.TestName = TestName AND ym.DEVName = DEVName AND ym. Dept = Dept 
)
```

If the structure of both tables are the same, `EXCEPT` is probably simpler.

Answer (score 0):

```
IF OBJECT_ID(N'tempdb..#table1') IS NOT NULL drop table #table1
IF OBJECT_ID(N'tempdb..#table2') IS NOT NULL drop table #table2

create table #table1 (id int, value varchar(10))
create table #table2 (id int)

insert into #table1(id, value) VALUES (1,'value1'), (2,'value2'), (3,'value3')
--test here. Comment next line
insert into #table2(id) VALUES (1) --Comment/Uncomment

select * from #table1
select * from #table2


select #table1.* 
from #table1 
left JOIN #table2 on 
    #table1.id = #table2.id
where (#table2.id is not null or not exists (select * from #table2))
```